# Custom classes in swagger

Tags: c#, swagger, asp.net-core-5.0

I have a c# webapi that takes a custom model parameter. When I run the app and go to the swagger Intex page, the parameter does not show. I believe it's because it only accepts standard data types. Is there a way to annotate my model so that it will show up on the index page?

Comment: Beyond such attributes as    [Produces(typeof(...))] and [Consumes(typeof(...)]?

Comment: Misha130, are you referring to the Customers attribute.ConsumesAttributes?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.producesattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0 and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.consumesattribute?view=aspnetcore-5.0 which swagger takes into consideration

Comment: Thanks you, but I believe these methods only refer to how the parameter is sent. For example Json or XML. I need swagger to recognize my parameter is a model of type customclass. I can currently sent my model using postman but not using the swagger interface.

Comment: It turns out that my model is not being analysed by API explorer because it is in a different assembly. I tested this by moving the model into my assembly and swagger processed it appropriately. I have searched to see how to add assemblies to API explorer, but I have not found any documentation as of yet.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue by modifying the model project to also produce a XML document file and included that file in the setup of Swagger.